# Storing an address or NULL at an address relative to a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I was wondering if there is a way I can store a NULL value or an address at an address relative to a pointer by using pointer arithmetic in C.

```
int *p;
p = NULL;  // is possible

int *p, *q;
p + 1 = NULL;  // ERROR: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
p + 1 = q;     // ERROR: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

Comment: I don't think the first one (`p = NULL`) is doing what you think it is. To be sure, what do you think it's doing?

Comment: `(p+1) = NULL` might work, I've never tried something like it.  Using an array index is usually the preferred method though, as Jim showed.  Storing a null value shouldn't be a problem presuming you have access to the space in memory.

Comment: I am trying to make the next word from p point to NULL. Basically I am trying to implement a linked list by storing the address to the next pointer one word next to the previous pointer.

Comment: @Namfuak I tried the (p+1) = NULL approach. It does not work.

Comment: You'll need to use indexing or a temporary variable then.  Dpesm

Comment: Well, you can rewrite `p+1 = NULL` as `p = NULL-1`, that will compile, but I'm not sure this is really what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to do something like this, assuming `p` points to a valid piece of memory that you have rights to writing to:

```
int **p = something;
p[1] = NULL;
p[1] = q;
```

Comment: Is it not possible to do this without using a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: Sure, it's possible if you use casting, but why would you do this rather than use the correct types?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't exactly clear to me what you are asking.  You can set a pointer to a NULL value and you can point to a value that is NULL.  You cannot set a pointer to NULL then attempt to use it as a target for a value.  Here is an example of using pointer arithmetic

```
 int *p = (int*) malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
 *p = 0; // dereference p and set it's value to 0
 *(p + 1) = 1; // add 1 sizeof(int) to p and set it's value to 1
```

NULL is just an alias for 0.

Comment: I am only setting it to null as an indicator that it is not assigned. When I have a value to be stored there, I want it to point to the address where it is stored. q in the example above.

Comment: That sounds a lot like you want a pointer to a pointer (int **p, *q;)  Unfortunately, in your example p is never set to it's difficult to know your intention.  If you want a pointer to a pointer you would still have something like this: *(p + 1) = q;

Answer (score 0):

```
int *p, *q;

*(unsigned int *)(p + 1) =  (intptr_t)NULL;
// or
*(unsigned int *)(p + 1) =  (intptr_t)q;
```

This seemed to work for me.